# Strange repeated field error when uploading to BigQuery with Pandas or command line. All fields unique

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a pandas dataframe that I have also written to file. I have also created a schema for the data in json format. I have this stored as a python dictionary, and also written to file.

I've tried uploading using `to_gpq` and using the command line, and in both instances, I get an error about having a repeated field, the same field.

This is info about the data:

*code*

```py
df.shape
len(clinvar_variant_schema)
schema_fields = [x['name'] for x in clinvar_variant_schema]
schema_fields.sort()
json.dumps(schema_fields)
colnames = df.columns.tolist()
colnames.sort()
json.dumps(colnames)
set(schema_fields).difference(set(colnames))
set(colnames).difference(set(schema_fields))
```

*output*

```py
(1000, 24)

24

'["AF_ESP", "AF_EXAC", "AF_TGP", "ALLELEID", "ALT", "CHROM", "CLNDISDB", "CLNDN", "CLNHGVS", "CLNREVSTAT", "CLNSIG", "CLNSIGCONF", "CLNVC", "CLNVCSO", "CLNVI", "FILTER", "GENEINFO", "ID", "MC", "ORIGIN", "POS", "QUAL", "REF", "RS"]'

'["AF_ESP", "AF_EXAC", "AF_TGP", "ALLELEID", "ALT", "CHROM", "CLNDISDB", "CLNDN", "CLNHGVS", "CLNREVSTAT", "CLNSIG", "CLNSIGCONF", "CLNVC", "CLNVCSO", "CLNVI", "FILTER", "GENEINFO", "ID", "MC", "ORIGIN", "POS", "QUAL", "REF", "RS"]'

set()

set()

      Colnames Schema_Names
0       AF_ESP       AF_ESP
1      AF_EXAC      AF_EXAC
2       AF_TGP       AF_TGP
3     ALLELEID     ALLELEID
4          ALT          ALT
5        CHROM        CHROM
6     CLNDISDB     CLNDISDB
7        CLNDN        CLNDN
8      CLNHGVS      CLNHGVS
9   CLNREVSTAT   CLNREVSTAT
10      CLNSIG       CLNSIG
11  CLNSIGCONF   CLNSIGCONF
12       CLNVC        CLNVC
13     CLNVCSO      CLNVCSO
14       CLNVI        CLNVI
15      FILTER       FILTER
16    GENEINFO     GENEINFO
17          ID           ID
18          MC           MC
19      ORIGIN       ORIGIN
20         POS          POS
21        QUAL         QUAL
22         REF          REF
23          RS           RS
```

### Using Pandas

```py
project_id = "my_project_id"
table_id = "my_dataset.clinvar_vcf"
df.to_gbq(
    destination_table = table_id,
    project_id = project_id,
    if_exists = "replace",
    table_schema = clinvar_variant_schema
)
```

```py
IPython will make a temporary file named: /tmp/ipython_edit_pw1v55fy/ipython_edit_k3v1q7m5.py

1it [00:00,  2.93it/s]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidResponse                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in load_table_from_file(self, file_obj, destination, rewind, size, num_retries, job_id, job_id_prefix, location, project, job_config)
   1829                 response = self._do_resumable_upload(
-> 1830                     file_obj, job_resource, num_retries
   1831                 )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in _do_resumable_upload(self, stream, metadata, num_retries)
   2153         upload, transport = self._initiate_resumable_upload(
-> 2154             stream, metadata, num_retries
   2155         )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in _initiate_resumable_upload(self, stream, metadata, num_retries)
   2195         upload.initiate(
-> 2196             transport, stream, metadata, _GENERIC_CONTENT_TYPE, stream_final=False
   2197         )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/upload.py in initiate(self, transport, stream, metadata, content_type, total_bytes, stream_final, timeout)
    411         )
--> 412         self._process_initiate_response(response)
    413         return response

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_upload.py in _process_initiate_response(self, response)
    505             self._get_status_code,
--> 506             callback=self._make_invalid,
    507         )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_helpers.py in require_status_code(response, status_codes, get_status_code, callback)
    110             u"Expected one of",
--> 111             *status_codes
    112         )

InvalidResponse: ('Request failed with status code', 400, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.CREATED: 201>)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

BadRequest                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in load_data(self, dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize, schema, progress_bar)
    628                 chunks = tqdm.tqdm(chunks)
--> 629             for remaining_rows in chunks:
    630                 logger.info(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tqdm/std.py in __iter__(self)
   1173         try:
-> 1174             for obj in iterable:
   1175                 yield obj

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/load.py in load_chunks(client, dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize, schema, location)
     81                 job_config=job_config,
---> 82                 location=location,
     83             ).result()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in load_table_from_file(self, file_obj, destination, rewind, size, num_retries, job_id, job_id_prefix, location, project, job_config)
   1836         except resumable_media.InvalidResponse as exc:
-> 1837             raise exceptions.from_http_response(exc.response)
   1838 

BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/eacri-genomics/jobs?uploadType=resumable: Cannot load CSV data with a repeated field. Field: FILTER

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

GenericGBQException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-19cb6dc0a4ee> in <module>
      6     project_id = project_id,
      7     if_exists = "replace",
----> 8     table_schema = clinvar_variant_schema
      9 )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_gbq(self, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, progress_bar, credentials)
   1655             location=location,
   1656             progress_bar=progress_bar,
-> 1657             credentials=credentials,
   1658         )
   1659 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, progress_bar, credentials, verbose, private_key)
    226         credentials=credentials,
    227         verbose=verbose,
--> 228         private_key=private_key,
    229     )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, progress_bar, credentials, verbose, private_key)
   1206         chunksize=chunksize,
   1207         schema=table_schema,
-> 1208         progress_bar=progress_bar,
   1209     )
   1210 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in load_data(self, dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize, schema, progress_bar)
    634                 )
    635         except self.http_error as ex:
--> 636             self.process_http_error(ex)
    637 
    638     def schema(self, dataset_id, table_id):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in process_http_error(ex)
    433         # <https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors>`__
    434 
--> 435         raise GenericGBQException("Reason: {0}".format(ex))
    436 
    437     def run_query(

GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/eacri-genomics/jobs?uploadType=resumable: Cannot load CSV data with a repeated field. Field: FILTER
```

### Using Command Line `bq`

```py
bq load --source_format=CSV --field_delimiter=tab --replace --schema clinvar_variant_schema.json  my_project_id:my_dataset.clinvar_vcf clinvar_expanded_vcf
```

```py
BigQuery error in load operation: Cannot load CSV data with a repeated field.
Field: FILTER

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-be7b46a6694c> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bash', '', 'bq load --source_format=CSV --field_delimiter=tab --replace --schema clinvar_variant_schema.json  eacri-genomics:clinvar_9302020.clinvar_vcf clinvar_expanded_vcf\n')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2379             with self.builtin_trap:
   2380                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2381                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2382             return result
   2383 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in named_script_magic(line, cell)
    140             else:
    141                 line = script
--> 142             return self.shebang(line, cell)
    143 
    144         # write a basic docstring:

<decorator-gen-103> in shebang(self, line, cell)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in shebang(self, line, cell)
    243             sys.stderr.flush()
    244         if args.raise_error and p.returncode!=0:
--> 245             raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cell, output=out, stderr=err)
    246 
    247     def _run_script(self, p, cell, to_close):

CalledProcessError: Command 'b'bq load --source_format=CSV --field_delimiter=tab --replace --schema clinvar_variant_schema.json  eacri-genomics:clinvar_9302020.clinvar_vcf clinvar_expanded_vcf\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you do not have `'mode': 'REPEATED'` in your `clinvar_variant_schema`. Also check if the table `clinvar_vcf` already exists in BigQuery and mode of it's columns.

Comment: Why is there a mode called repeated if it breaks uploading? So, if the schema says repeated, and the data is a csv, but the data has no repeated data, it still fails?

Comment: REPEATED is like a synonym of "array". Consider using [client.load_table_from_dataframe](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html?highlight=load_table_from_file#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_dataframe) which supports REPEATED partially. REPEATED is fully supported by [Client.load_table_from_json](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html?highlight=load_table_from_file#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_json).

Comment: Yep, csv is not compatible with repeated column in schema. Maybe makes sense just to delete `'mode': 'REPEATED'` from `clinvar_variant_schema` if there is no repeated data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like CSV does not support nested or repeated data.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#limitations

I believe by default to_gbq converts to CSV and then loads.  So you may want to potentially use another format other than CSV.

Comment: I don't have any nested data.

Comment: so the column FILTER is not repeated and by that i mean does it contain a list of any kind?

Comment: I read in the data into pandas from a flat CSV file. Is there a way you can think of where I can check for such an issue?

Comment: I would search the values in the FILTER column for square brackets, or put it into sheets and do the same.  Can you share what some of the FILTER data looks like

Comment: also another option you could do is use the to_parquet function and load that instead of a csv

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of [Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13473525/sergey-geron)

You indeed should use the "REPEATED" mode

```
bq_schema = [
     SchemaField(name="sp_zipcode", field_type="STRING", mode="REPEATED", description="Search query parameter: zipcode")
]
```

This still caused `Cannot load CSV data with a repeated field. Field: sp_zipcode`

This was resolved for me by upgrading the requirements

```
pip install google-cloud-bigquery --upgrade
pip install pandas-gbq --upgrade
```

```
google-cloud-bigquery==2.32.0
pandas-gbq==0.17.0
```

Here is the entire pip freeze after installing the 2 packages:

```
cachetools==5.0.0
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.11
db-dtypes==0.3.1
google-api-core==2.4.0
google-auth==2.6.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-cloud-bigquery==2.32.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.11.0
google-cloud-core==2.2.2
google-crc32c==1.3.0
google-resumable-media==2.1.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.54.0
grpcio==1.43.0
grpcio-status==1.43.0
idna==3.3
libcst==0.4.1
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
numpy==1.21.5
oauthlib==3.2.0
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.3.5
pandas-gbq==0.17.0
proto-plus==1.19.9
protobuf==3.19.4
pyarrow==6.0.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pydata-google-auth==1.3.0
pyparsing==3.0.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.8
six==1.16.0
typing-extensions==4.0.1
typing-inspect==0.7.1
urllib3==1.26.8
```